# Is it possible to use "boost::spirit::qi::as_string" in a loop? If so, can someone help me find the solution?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, tokenize, boost-spirit-qi

I am splitting my string based on two delimiters so far, but I would like to extend this to a possibility where the number of delimiters is variable. Right now, I have this function:

```
void dac_sim::dac_ifs::dac_sim_subcmd_if::parse_cmd(std::string command, std::array<std::string, 2> delimiters)
{
  std::string str = command;
  std::vector< std::string > vec;

  auto it = str.begin(), end = str.end();
  bool res = boost::spirit::qi::parse(it, end,
    boost::spirit::qi::as_string[ *(boost::spirit::qi::char_ - delimiters[0] - delimiters[1]) ] % (boost::spirit::qi::lit(delimiters[0]) | boost::spirit::qi::lit(delimiters[1])),
    vec);

  std::cout << "Parsed:";
  for (auto const& s : vec)
    std::cout << " \"" << s << "\"";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

But now I want something more generic, via template for the array size, like this:

```
template <size_t N>
void dac_sim::dac_ifs::dac_sim_subcmd_if::parse_cmd(std::string command, std::array<std::string, N> delimiters)
```

In this case, how can I procceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fold Expressions

Can you use c++17? I'd use fold-expressions:

```
auto parse_cmd(std::string_view str, auto const&... delim) {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(),
              qi::as_string[*(qi::char_ - ... - delim)] % (qi::lit(delim) | ...) //
                  > qi::eoi,
              vec);

    return vec;
}
```

Test it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57c939c1cf2bb80e)**

```
for (auto input :
     {
         "",
         "|",
         "|,",
         "|,||",
         "foo||bar,qux,stux;net||more||||to,come",
     }) //
{
    fmt::print("{:<30} -> {}\n", fmt::format("'{}'", input), parse_cmd(input, "||", ","));
}
```

Prints

```
''              -> [""]
'|'             -> ["|"]
'|,'            -> ["|", ""]
'|,||'          -> ["|", "", ""]
'foo||bar,qux,stux;net||more||||to,come' -> ["foo", "bar", "qux", "stux;net", "more", "", "to", "come"]
```

### But You Need Arrays?

You can always use the index-sequence trick to transform into a parameter pack:

```
template <size_t N>
auto parse_cmd(std::string_view str, std::array<std::string, N> const& delims) {
    return [&]<size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return do_parse_cmd(str, delims[I]...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Where `do_parse_cmd` is the function just shown above. Let's demo with `";"` added as a third delimiter: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff386aa8a07dd4a4)**

```
std::array<std::string, 3> delimiters{"||", ",", ";"};

for (auto input :
     {
         "",
         "|",
         "|,",
         "|,||",
         "foo||bar,qux,stux;net||more||||to,come",
     }) //
{
    fmt::print("{:<15} -> {}\n", fmt::format("'{}'", input), parse_cmd(input, delimiters));
}
```

Prints

```
''              -> [""]
'|'             -> ["|"]
'|,'            -> ["|", ""]
'|,||'          -> ["|", "", ""]
'foo||bar,qux,stux;net||more||||to,come' -> ["foo", "bar", "qux", "stux", "net", "more", "", "to", "come"]
```

> *Note how `stux;net` is correctly split now.*

### Problems

- versions
- semantic problems
- flexibility

#### Versions

For one, the above requires c++17 for the fold-expressions, and the demos also liberally use c++20 features to make it all easy to demonstrate. If you don't have that, even the c++17 version will become a lot more tedious.

#### Semantic problems

There's an issue when the caller passes delimiters in a sub-optimal way. E.g., `{":", ":|:"}` won't work, but `{":|:", ":"}` will. That's because of the overlapping pattern. You would want to be smarter.

#### Flexibility

You might want to be able to have full-blown parser expression capability instead of fixed string literals. Let me postpone this for later

## Qi Symbols

To support c++11 and solve the semantic issue, let's use `qi::symbols`:

```
using tokens = std::vector<std::string>;

template <size_t N> tokens
parse_cmd(std::string const& str, std::array<std::string, N> const& delims) {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    qi::symbols<char> delim;
    for (auto& d : delims)
        delim += d;

    tokens vec;
    parse(str.begin(), str.end(), qi::as_string[*(qi::char_ - delim)] % delim > qi::eoi, vec);
    return vec;
}
```

This internally builds a Trie so the order in which delimiters are passed doesn't matter. The longest possible match will always match a single `delim` expression.

With the same test: **[Live On Coliru (c++11)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a37a9a33680537a)**

```
''              -> [""]
'|'             -> ["|"]
'|,'            -> ["|", ""]
'|,||'          -> ["|", "", ""]
'foo||bar,qux,stux;net||more||||to,come' -> ["foo", "bar", "qux", "stux", "net", "more", "", "to", "come"]
```

## Future Proofing

To be completely flexible and compose the parser from any parser expression, you would have to thread the needle in Qi, and get considerable compile times:

- [Boost Qi Composing rules using Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812715/boost-qi-composing-rules-using-functions/27816065#27816065)
- [Generating Spirit parser expressions from a variadic list of alternative parser expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177184/generating-spirit-parser-expressions-from-a-variadic-list-of-alternative-parser/16181550#16181550)
- [spirit::qi: Combining parser_factory fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029434/spiritqi-combining-parser-factory-fails/39211690#39211690)
- [C++ Boost qi recursive rule construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405500/c-boost-qi-recursive-rule-construction/17408206#17408206)

Suffice it to say, I won't recommend it. However, using X3¹ none of this is hard, and you could easily achieve it

### Identical X3 version

Live On **[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/368798282cae8844)**. 'Nuff said

### Generalize (Computer, Enhance!)

Basically replacing `std::string` with `auto` in the fold-expression variant:

```
auto parse_cmd(std::string const& str, auto... delims) {
    tokens vec;
    parse(str.begin(), str.end(),
          *(x3::char_ - ... - x3::as_parser(delims)) //
                  % (x3::as_parser(delims) | ...)    //
              > x3::eoi,
          vec);
    return vec;
}
```

Now you can do funky stuff, like: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e92db42bb441bcea)**

```
static constexpr auto input = "foo (false) bar (   true ) qux (4.8e-9) <!-- any comment --> quz";
fmt::print("input: '{}'\n", input);

auto test = [](auto name, auto... p) {
    fmt::print("{:>5}: {}\n", name, parse_cmd(input, p...));
};

constexpr auto d = "(" >> x3::double_ >> ")";
constexpr auto b = x3::skip(x3::blank)["(" >> x3::bool_ >> ")"];
constexpr auto x = "<!--" >> *(x3::char_ - "-->") >> "-->";

test("d", d);
test("b", b);
test("x", x);
test("x|b|d", x, b, d);
```

Printing

```
input: 'foo (false) bar (   true ) qux (4.8e-9) <!-- any comment --> quz'
    d: ["foo (false) bar (   true ) qux ", " <!-- any comment --> quz"]
    b: ["foo", " bar", " qux (4.8e-9) <!-- any comment --> quz"]
    x: ["foo (false) bar (   true ) qux (4.8e-9) ", " quz"]
x|b|d: ["foo", " bar", " qux ", " ", " quz"]
```

### Summary/TL;DR

Combining parsers in X3 is a joy, and crazy powerful. It will typically still be faster to compile than the Qi parsers.

Note that at no point in this answer did I question why you are reinventing tokenization using a (checks notes) parser generator. Perhaps you should tell me what you're actually building or parsing, and I could give you some real advice on how to use Spirit for great success :)

---

¹ which is c++14 only and will become c++17 only in the future

Comment: Really really nice answer, I ve learned a lot with that. Thank you very very much :)

Comment: answering your question... I am given a command string and need to do some action based on that. For example: 

I get the command:  
Create<file>filename<path>path or Write<bit>bitnumber<port>portnumber<something>something... (there are several possible combinations and several commands) I used std::map for the  command<subcommand> (Create<file> for example) and that expects an argument, which would be the filename<path>path. At that point I would need a parse to separate the filename from <path> and then do what is needed according to the command.